# Looping through specific columns to create lists based on logical statements in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am fairly new to Python and could really use help. I have approximately 1200 subjects and 40 PTSD items, which I want to process.

Here is a table with example data:

| SubjectID | PTSD1 | PTSD2 | PTSD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1223 | YES | NO | YES |
| 1224 | NO | NO | YES |
| 1225 | YES | NO | NO |
| 1226 | YES | NO | NO |

As CSV:

```
SubjectID,PTSD1,PTSD2,PTSD3
1223,YES,NO,YES
1224,NO,NO,YES
1225,YES,NO,NO
1226,YES,NO,NO
```

I would like to write a for loop (or any other function) which allows me to go through each subject and create a list of all of the PTSD items they endorsed. I was just hoping to add a column with all of the items (PTSD1, PTSD2, etc) that a subject responded 'YES' to.

I was hoping to use the column header as a variable so I could do it on all 40 columns at once (although this isn't necessary).

After that, I was hoping to do the opposite and create a list of all the subjects who endorsed each PTSD item.

Any tips at all to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a couple sample lines of the data you have, in its current form, so we can help you transform it into the table you want?

Comment: What is the data structure of the table, a nested list or is it stored in a specific file format?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Vedant36 it is in an excel sheet right now, but I also have it in CSV format

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy the data shown at the bottom of the question is the way I have the data in its current form. Is there a way I can make it more clear? I was just hoping to add a column with all of the items (PTSD1, PTSD2, etc) that a subject responded 'YES' to. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: @anon I updated my answer to add a column with the "YES" items. You can comment on that below under the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to help you get started. The details depend on what exactly you want to do and how you want to structure the output data.

You can store your table in a CSV file (`data.csv`) with this content:

```
SubjectID,PTSD1,PTSD2,PTSD3
1223,YES,NO,YES
1224,NO,NO,YES
1225,YES,NO,NO
1226,YES,NO,NO
```

Then process it with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# go through each subject and create a list of all of the PTSD items they endorsed
def subject_responses(subject_id):
    return df.loc[df['SubjectID'] == subject_id]
    
print(subject_responses(1225))
#    SubjectID PTSD1 PTSD2 PTSD3
# 2       1225   YES    NO    NO

# create a list of all the subjects who endorsed each PTSD item
def response_subjects(ptsd_item):
    return df.loc[df[ptsd_item] == "YES"]
    
print(response_subjects("PTSD1"))    
# 0    1223
# 2    1225
# 3    1226

# add a column with all of the items (PTSD1, PTSD2, etc) that a subject responded 'YES' to
def get_items(row):
    items = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        item = 'PTSD'+str(i)
        if row[item] == "YES":       
            items.append(item)
    return ','.join(items)
    
df['PTSD_ITEMS'] = df.apply(get_items, axis=1)
print(df)

#    SubjectID PTSD1 PTSD2 PTSD3   PTSD_ITEMS
# 0       1223   YES    NO   YES  PTSD1,PTSD3
# 1       1224    NO    NO   YES        PTSD3
# 2       1225   YES    NO    NO        PTSD1
# 3       1226   YES    NO    NO        PTSD1
```

Comment: `df1 = df.replace({'NO': 0, 'YES': 1})`;
`df1.set_index('SubjectID', inplace=True)`;
`df['new'] = df1.dot(df1.columns+ ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').tolist()`

Comment: You can use pandas `dot` also after converting `Yes,No` to `1,0` values.